# Types in Specialized Python Generic class

Tags: python, generics, typing

Consider the following generic class, which is then specialized.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

class X(Generic[T1, T2]):
    x: T1
    y: T2

class Y(Generic[T], X[float, T]):
    pass

class Z(Y[int]):
    pass
```

Is there a way to get the specialization values of `Z`, in this case `(float, int)`?

As the order is important, the following example should

```py
class Y(Generic[T], X[T, float]):
    pass

class Z(Y[int]):
    pass
```

should return `(int, float)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type parameters as the class's `__args__`, and walk the inheritance tree recursively to get all the parameters:

```
def all_class_args(cls):
    args = []
    if hasattr(cls, '__origin__'):
        args.extend(all_class_args(cls.__origin__))
    if hasattr(cls, '__args__'):
        args.extend(cls.__args__)
    if hasattr(cls, '__orig_bases__'):
        args.extend(
            a
            for base in cls.__orig_bases__
            for a in all_class_args(base)
            if isinstance(a, type)
        )
    return args

print(all_class_args(Z))  # [<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>]
```

Comment: The only problem that I see with this approach is that (I think) it does not respect the order in the original class right?. i.e. I need that the order is always `T1`, `T2`